# Using Jespa with wsimport generated client to call a .net webservice protected by Windows Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jespa

I am trying to figure out how I can hook up Jespa into the client generated by wsimport, so that I can hook up to a .Net service that is using windows authentication (the java client is running on Linux, so the built in ntlm authentication doesn't work). I would be grateful for any working examples.

Also, I can't change any global settings because this is just a small module of a large system.

Comment: Hi @Grzenio, do you have solved it?

Comment: @IgnacioOcampo, I gave up after a while I am afraid :(

Comment: I solved it as a single library app. But when I load it in Tomcat it does not work.

Comment: Hi @Grzenio I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know